# Analytical solution to equation $ \arctan(x)-k \arctan(x/k)=c$

Tags: trigonometry, roots

For the equation:$$\arctan(x)-k \arctan(x/k)=c$$ which is part of a gasdynamics function called Prandtl–Meyer function, it is not difficult to find the solution numerically, however, I'm wondering, does the analytical solution exists? Thanks.
An example for the coefficient is $k=2.4$, $c=-1.4$, the solution is $x=5.57$.

Comment: This is a [transcendental equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) for which no closed form solution exists in general.

Comment: As Lucian wrote, except for specific integer values (or inverse of integer) of $k$, the equation has no analytical solution.

Answer (score 1):

After substituting $a\to i a,b\to ib,c\to e^{-2i c}$ and simplifying the [Lagrange inversion](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj4stfBj_j7AhXwEGIAHV5mCE8QFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FLagrange_inversion_theorem&usg=AOvVaw2XH3odpAHxrnUfpyUxoxun):

$$e^{2a\tanh^{-1}(bx)-2\tanh^{-1}(x)}=c\implies x=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-c)^n}{n!}\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{dw^{n-1}}\left(\left((w+1)(1-bw)^a (bw+1)^{-a}\right)^n\right)\right|_{w=1}$$

[**shown here**](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5Bexp%28-2+tanh%5E%28-1%29%28x%29+%2B+2+e+tanh%5E%28-1%29%28baxter+x%29%29-eulergamma%2C10%5D%2Cx%3D1%2Bsum%5B%28eulergamma%29%5En%2Fn%21+D%5B%28%28w-1%29%2F%28-%28%28-1+%2B+w%29+%281+-+baxter+w%29%5E%28-e%29+%281+%2B+baxter+w%29%5Ee%29%2F%281+%2B+w%29%29%29%5En%2C%7Bw%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C6%7D%5D%2Cw%3D1.0). Now to use the [generalized product rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4552386/alternate-multinomial-theorem-for-fracdndxn-prod-limits-k-1m-f-kx) and expanding. The result will be a double hypergeometric series converging for values similar to the “shown here” link. More will develop in the series expansion.

Answer (score 0):

The fuction
$$f(x)=k \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)-\tan ^{-1}(x)-c$$ being odd, just consider the positive roots for $k>1$ and $c>0$.

The function being rather flat around the origin, if $c$ is "sufficiently" large, using Taylor series and power series reversion to obtain
$$x=t-\sum_{n=0}^p \frac{P_n(k)}{b_n}\,\frac 1{t^{2n+1}} \quad \text{where}\quad t=\frac{2(k^2-1)}{(k-1)\pi-2c}  $$

Coefficients $b_n$ correspond to the $a_{n+1}$ in sequence  $A036278$ at $OEIS$ and the first polynomials are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & P_n(k) \\
 0 & (k^2+1) \\
 1 & k^4+11 k^2+1 \\
 2 & 2 \left(k^2+1\right) \left(k^4+56 k^2+1\right) \\
 3 & k^8+247 k^6+723 k^4+247 k^2+1 \\
 4 & 2 \left(k^2+1\right) \left(k^8+1012 k^6+5028 k^4+1012
   k^2+1\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ We can easily as many as desired since the coefficients of the intial series are more than simple

$$k \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)-\tan ^{-1}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{k^{2(n+1)}-1}{(2n+1)\, x^{2n+1}}$$