# Inverse of difference of two digamma functions

Tags: inverse-function, digamma-function

I recently encountered the expression below for which I was interested in solving for $x$:

\begin{equation}
\psi(x+n+1) - \psi(x+1) =y
\end{equation}

$\psi$ is the digamma function, $n$ is a positive integer and $x,y>0$. Initially, I solved this numerically but I was interested to see if there was the possibility to solve this, either in closed form or as a series. I tried to find some way by using the relationship to harmonic numbers, e.g. rewriting as

\begin{equation}
\psi(x+n+1) - \psi(x+1) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k+x} = \int_0^1 \frac{t^x(1-t^n)}{1-t}dt
\end{equation}

to see if there was something which I could do, but I didn't notice anything apparent. The only thing I've come up with is that for large values of $x$, $y$ is small and using $\psi(x) \sim\ln(x)$, that $x \approx \dfrac{n}{e^y - 1}$.

I'm happy for any suggestions on how to proceed!

Comment: Cases, up to [$n=4$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+of+1%2F%281+%2B+x%29+%2B+1%2F%282+%2B+x%29+%2B+1%2F%283+%2B+x%29%2B1%2F%28x%2B4%29), have a closed form inverse, so inverting $\frac1{x+1}+\dots+\frac1{x+n}$ will be like inverting a [polynomial](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=inverse+of+1%2F%281+%2B+x%29+%2B+1%2F%282+%2B+x%29+%2B+1%2F%283+%2B+x%29%2B1%2F%28x%2B4%29%2B1%2F%28x%2B5%29).

Comment: Yes, you are right @Gary! I changed notation when typing the question. Now it should be fixed.

Comment: What is $t$ at the end?

Comment: Same goes for that part, I should probably try to stick to my initial notation and not change things :)

Comment: If you use the better approximation $\psi(z+1) \approx \log(z+1/2)$ you get $$x\approx \frac{n}{\mathrm{e}^y-1}-\frac{1}{2}.$$

Comment: Are you looking for an explicit solution?

Comment: @TymaGaidash, if it is possible yes, but mostly I'm trying to learn more about the problem at hand and what can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\F{\operatorname F}\def\H{\operatorname H}$**Derivation:** After different [Lagrange reversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) setups, this one had the simplest derivation without needing to factor. Additionally, less series are possible with [Tschirnhausen transformations](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TschirnhausenTransformation.html), but applying them to a degree $m$ polynomial in general is complicated. The [harmonic number H$_m$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Harmonic%28n%29) set up [includes $(0,0)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+e%5E%28harmonic%282%29-1%2F%28x%2B1%29-1%2F%28x%2B2%29%29-1%2C+e%5E%28-1%2F%28x%2B1%29-1%2F%28x%2B2%29%29+from+0+to+1): $$e^{\H_m-\sum\limits_{k=1}^m\frac1{y+k}}-1=x\implies y=x+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(x+1-e^{H_m}\prod_{k=1}^me^{-\frac1{x+k}}\right)^n$$ [shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2Fexp%281%2F%28y%2B1%29%2B1%2F%28y%2B2%29%2B1%2F%28y%2B3%29-harmonic%283%29%29-1%2Cy%3D0.25%2Bsum%5B1%2Fn%21+D%5B%28x-%281%2Fexp%281%2F%28x%2B1%29%2B1%2F%28x%2B2%29%2B1%2F%28x%2B3%29-harmonic%283%29%29-1%29%29%5En%2C%7Bx%2Cn-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C5%7D%5D%2Cx%3D0.25), so here is a solution directly without reducing the equation. Using the binomial theorem on the derivative: $$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left(x+1-e^{\H_m}\prod_{k=1}^me^{-\frac1{x+k}}\right)^n=\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj\left(-e^{\H_m}\right)^j\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left((x+1)^{n-j} \prod_{k=1}^me^{-\frac j{x+k}}\right)$$ Applying the [general Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) and [factorial power $a^{(b)}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=factorialpower&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22factorialpower%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22SloppyFunction%22%7D): $$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}\left((x+1)^{n-j} \prod_{k=1}^me^{-\frac j{x+k}}\right)=\sum_{v=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}v\frac{d^{n-1-v}}{dx^{n-1-v}}((x+1)^{n-j}) \frac{d^v}{dx^v}\left(\prod_{k=1}^me^{-\frac j{x+k}}\right)= \sum_{n_0=0}^{n-1} \binom{n-1}{n_0} (x+1)^{n_0-j+1}(n-j)^{(n-1-n_0)}\frac{d^{n_0}}{dx^{n_0}}\left(\prod_{k=1}^me^{-\frac j{x+k}}\right)$$ Also, we use the [generalized product rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4552386/alternate-multinomial-theorem-for-fracdndxn-prod-limits-k-1m-f-kx): $$\frac{d^{n_0}}{dx^{n_0}}\left(\prod_{k=1}^me^{-\frac j{x+k}}\right)= \sum_{n_1=0}^{n_0}\sum_{n_2=0}^{n_1}\dots\sum_{n_{m-1}=0}^{n_{m-2}}\frac{{n_0}!f_1^{(n_0-n_1)}f_m^{(n_{m-1})}}{(n_0-n_1)!n_{m-1}!}\prod_{k=2}^{m-1}\frac{f_k^{(n_{k-1}-n_k)}}{(n_{k-1}-n_k)!} $$ A formula with the [confluent hypergeometric $_1\F_1(a;b;z)$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=confluent+hypergeometric+function) function and [Kronecker $\delta_x,\delta_{x,y}$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=kroneckerdelta): $$\frac{d^r}{dx^r}e^{-\frac j{x+k}}=\sum_{u=0}^\infty\frac{(-j)^u}{u!}\frac{d^r}{dx^r}(x+k)^{-u}=\sum_{u=0}^\infty \frac{(-j)^u (-u)^{(r)}(x+k)^{-r-u}}{u!}=(x+k)^{-r}0^{(r)}-j(x+k)^{-r-1}(-1)^{(r)}\,_1\text F_1\left(r+1;2;-\frac j{x+k}\right)=\delta_r-j(-1)^r r!(x+k)^{-r-1}\,_1\text F_1\left(r+1;2;-\frac j{x+k}\right) $$ **Simple Verification:** Unfortunately, Wolfram Alpha [cannot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BSum%5BSum%5B%5C%2840%29binom%5C%2840%293%5C%2844%29j%5C%2841%29*binom%5C%2840%293-1%5C%2844%29v%5C%2841%29*binom%5C%2840%29v%5C%2844%29a%5C%2841%29*Power%5B-1%2Cj%5D*Power%5Be%2CDivide%5B3j%2C2%5D%5D*Power%5Bx%2B1%2Cv-j%2B1%5D*factorialpower%5C%2840%293-j%5C%2844%293-v-1%5C%2841%29*%5C%2840%29Divide%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29x%2B1%5C%2841%29%2Ca-v%5D%2C%5C%2840%29a-v%5C%2841%29%21%5D-jPower%5Bx%2B1%2Ca-v-1%5DPower%5B-1%2Cv-a%5D%5C%2840%29v-a%5C%2841%29%21*1F1%5C%2840%29+v-a%2B1%5C%2844%292%5C%2844%29-Divide%5Bj%2Cx%2B1%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29*%5C%2840%29Divide%5BPower%5Bx%2B1%2C-a%5D%2C%5C%2840%29-a%5C%2841%29%21%5D-j+Power%5B%5C%2840%29x%2B2%5C%2841%29%2C-a-1%5DPower%5B-1%2Ca%5Da%21+*1F1%5C%2840%29a%2B1%5C%2844%292%5C%2844%29-Divide%5Bj%2Cx%2B2%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C%7Ba%2C0%2Cv%7D%5D%2C%7Bv%2C0%2C3-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bj%2C0%2C3%7D%5D) evaluate the full sums, but does for a partly written sum. Let’s verify that the above steps work for $m=2$. Testing $n=3,x=0.3$ gives [matching](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F3%21+lim%5Bsum%5Bbinom%283%2Cj%29+%28-exp%28harmonic%282%29%29%29%5Ej+sum%5Bbinom%283-1%2Cv%29+D%5B%28x%2B1%29%5E%283-j%29%2C%7Bx%2C3-1-v%7D%5D+D%5B%28exp%28-j%2F%28x%2B1%29%29exp%28-j%2F%28x%2B2%29%29%29%2C%7Bx%2Cv%7D%5D%2C%7Bv%2C0%2C3-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bj%2C0%2C3%7D%5D%2Cx-%3E0.3%5D) [series coefficients](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F3%21+D%5B%28x%2B1-e%5Eharmonic%282%29+exp%28-1%2F%28x%2B1%29-1%2F%28x%2B2%29%29%29%5E3%2C%7Bx%2C3-1%7D%5D%2Cx%3D0.3). Thereafter, testing $\frac{d^v}{dx^v}\left(e^{-\frac j{x+1}-\frac j{x+2}}\right),j=4,v=3,x=0.3$ gives the [same](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5Be%5E%28-4%2F%28x%2B1%29-4%2F%28x%2B2%29%29%2C%7Bx%2C3%7D%5D%2Cx%3D0.3) [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim%5BSum%5Bbinom%283%2Ca%29%28%28x%2B1%29%5E%28-%283-a%29%29%2F%28-%283-a%29%29%21-4%28x%2B1%29%5E%28-%283-a%29-1%29factorialpower%28-1%2C3-a%291F1%283-a%2B1%2C2%2C-4%2F%28x%2B1%29%29%29%28%282+%2B+x%29%5E%28-a%29%2F%28-a%29%21-4+%28x%2B2%29%5E%28-a-1%29factorialpower%28-1%2Ca%29+1F1%28a%2B1%2C2%2C-4%2F%28x%2B2%29%29%29%2C%7Ba%2C0%2C3%7D%5D%2Cx-%3E0.3%5D). Similarly when $m=3$, we get [matching](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F4%21+lim%5Bsum%5Bbinom%284%2Cj%29+%28-exp%28harmonic%283%29%29%29%5Ej+sum%5Bbinom%284-1%2Cv%29+D%5B%28x%2B1%29%5E%284-j%29%2C%7Bx%2C4-1-v%7D%5D+D%5B%28exp%28-j+%281%2F%28x%2B1%29%2B1%2F%28x%2B2%29%2B1%2F%28x%2B3%29%29%29%29%2C%7Bx%2Cv%7D%5D%2C%7Bv%2C0%2C4-1%7D%5D%2C%7Bj%2C0%2C4%7D%5D%2Cx-%3E0.3%5D) [series coefficients](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F4%21+D%5B%28x%2B1-e%5Eharmonic%283%29+exp%28-%281%2F%28x%2B1%29%2B1%2F%28x%2B2%29%2B1%2F%28x%2B3%29%29%29%29%5E4%2C%7Bx%2C4-1%7D%5D%2Cx%3D0.3). Testing $\frac{d^v}{dx^v}\left(e^{-\frac j{x+1}-\frac j{x+2}-\frac j{x+3}}\right),v=4,j=5,x=0.3$ gives the [same](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=D%5B%28exp%28+-5*%281%2F%28x%2B1%29%2B1%2F%28x%2B2%29%2B1%2F%28x%2B3%29%29%29%29%2C%7Bx%2C4%7D%5D%2Cx%3D0.3) [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim%5Bsum%5Bsum%5Bbinom%284%2Ca%29*binom%28a%2Cb%29*D%5Bexp%28-5%2F%28x%2B1%29%29%2C%7Bx%2C4-a%7D%5DD%5Bexp%28-5%2F%28x%2B2%29%29%2C%7Bx%2Ca-b%7D%5DD%5Bexp%28-5%2F%28x%2B3%29%29%2C%7Bx%2Cb%7D%5D%2C%7Bb%2C0%2C4%7D%5D%2C%7Ba%2C0%2C4%7D%5D%2Cx-%3E0.3%5D). Wolfram Alpha [cannot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sum%5BSum%5BDivide%5B4%21%2C%5C%2840%294-a%5C%2841%29%21*b%21*%5C%2840%29a-b%5C%2841%29%21%5D*%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C%5C%2840%29-b%5C%2841%29%21%5D-5+factorialpower%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2844%29b%5C%2841%29Power%5B0.3%2B3%2C%5C%28123%29-b-1%5C%28125%29%5D*1F1%5C%2840%29b%2B1%5C%2844%292%5C%2844%29-Divide%5B5%2C0.3%2B3%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29*%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C%5C%2840%29a-4%5C%2841%29%21%5D-5+factorialpower%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2844%294-a%5C%2841%29Power%5B0.3%2B1%2C%5C%28123%29-%5C%2840%294-a%5C%2841%29-1%5C%28125%29%5D*1F1%5C%2840%294-a%2B1%5C%2844%292%5C%2844%29-Divide%5B5%2C0.3%2B1%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29*%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2C%5C%2840%29b-a%5C%2841%29%21%5D-5+factorialpower%5C%2840%29-1%5C%2844%29a-b%5C%2841%29Power%5B%5C%2840%290.3%2B2%5C%2841%29%2C%5C%28123%29-%5C%2840%29a-b%5C%2841%29-1%5C%28125%29%5D*1F1%5C%2840%29a-b%5C%2844%292%5C%2844%29-Divide%5B5%2C0.3%2B2%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bb%2C0%2Ca%7D%5D%2C%7Ba%2C0%2C4%7D%5D) evaluate the derivatives as confluent hypergeometric functions, but the derived $\frac{d^r}{dx^r} e^{-\frac j{x+k}}$ formula is [true](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=N%5B-D%5Be%5E%28-j%2F%28x%2Bk%29%29%2C%7Bx%2C5%7D%5D%2Bkroneckerdelta%28r%29-j+%28x%2Bk%29%5E%28-r-1%29+factorialpower%28-1%2Cr%29+1F1%28r%2B1%2C2%2C-j%2F%28x%2Bk%29%29%2C5%5D%2Cr%3D5%2Cj%3Deulergamma%2Ck%3Dkhinchin%2Cx%3D1%2Fe) presents no convergence issues. Other values of $v,j,x$, including $v,j=0$, work when $m=2,3$ and combining verification links give evidence for the Lagrange reversion result working when $m>3$ **Formula:** Therefore we should get: $$\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1{y+k}=x\implies y=\H_m-\ln\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj\left(-e^{\H_m}\right)^j \sum_{n_0=0}^{n-1}(x+1)^{n_0-j+1}(n-1)^{(n_0)}(n-j)^{(n-1-n_0)} \sum_{n_1=0}^{n_0}\sum_{n_2=0}^{n_1}\dots\sum_{n_{m-1}=0}^{n_{m-2}}\left(\frac{\delta_{n_0,n_1}} {(n_0-n_1)!}-j(-1)^{n_0-n_1}(x+1)^{n_1-n_0-1}\,_1\text F_1\left(n_0-n_1+1;2;-\frac j{x+1}\right)\right) \left(\frac{\delta_{n_{m-1}}} {n_{m-1}!}-j(-1)^{n_{m-1}}(x+m)^{-n_{m-1}-1}\,_1\text F_1\left(n_{m-1}+1;2;-\frac j{x+m}\right)\right)\prod_{k=2}^{m-1}\left(\frac{\delta_{n_{k-1},n_k}} {(n_{k-1}-n_k)!}-j(-1)^{n_{k-1}-n_k}(x+k)^{n_k-n_{k-1}-1}\,_1\text F_1\left(n_{k-1}-n_k +1;2;-\frac j{x+k}\right)\right) \right)= \boxed{\H_m-\ln\left(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{n_0=0}^{n-1}\frac{\Gamma(n)n! (x+1)^{n_0-j+1} \left(-e^{\H_m}\right)^j}{(v-j+1)!\Gamma(n-v)j!}\sum_{0\le n_{m-1}\le\dots\le n_0}\left(\frac{\delta_{n_{m-1}}} {n_{m-1}!}-j(-1)^{n_{m-1}}(x+m)^{-n_{m-1}-1}\,_1\text F_1\left(n_{m-1}+1;2;-\frac j{x+m}\right)\right)\prod_{k=1}^{m-1}\left(\frac{\delta_{n_{k-1},n_k}} {(n_{k-1}-n_k)!}-j(-1)^{n_{k-1}-n_k}(x+k)^{n_k-n_{k-1}-1}\,_1\text F_1\left(n_{k-1}-n_k +1;2;-\frac j{x+k}\right)\right) \right)}$$ **Closed form?:** Since solving $\sum\limits_{k=1}^m\frac1{y+k}=x$ is solving a polynomial, you use the [Riemann theta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_formula) [function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SiegelTheta.html), but this is too advanced for some.

Comment: If one wants to reduce the polynomial equation, then it will give a  series expansion with less series than above. However, it is tedious and new to me for a general $m$ degree polynomial from solving $\sum\limits_{n=1}^m\frac1{y+m}=x$. There are $m+2$ sums in this solution and with [these transformations](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TschirnhausenTransformation.html), the Lagrange reversion solution could give $m-4$ sums.

Comment: Thank you @TymaGaidash! I’ve read through your calculations a couple of times and seem to understund the steps. The answer is quite a brute though! I’ll try to repeat your calculations so I understand it in detail. Regarding the theta function, I’ve only encountered it once briefly, but maybe that’s something to look at one day :)

Answer (score 2):

$$\psi(x+n+1) - \psi(x+1) =y$$

For large values of $x$, the lhs write
$$\frac{n}{x}-\frac{n (n+1)}{2 x^2}+\frac{n (n+1) (2 n+1)}{6
   x^3}-\frac{n^2 (n+1)^2}{4
   x^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^5}\right)$$ Using series reversion
$$x_{(1)}=\frac{n}{y}-\frac{n+1}{2}+\frac{\left(n^2-1\right)}{12
   n}y+O\left(y^3\right)$$

Comparing with your approximation
$$x_{(2)}= \dfrac{n}{e^y - 1}=\frac{n}{y}-\frac{n}{2}+\frac{n }{12}y+O\left(y^3\right)$$ It is really good since
$$x_{(2)}-x_{(1)}=-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{y}{12 n}+O\left(y^3\right)$$

Using the above for $n=1000$ and $y=1$, the exact solution is $581.477$ while $x_{(2)}=582.833$ and $\frac{1000}{e-1}=581.977$.

**Edit**

We could do better using more terms in the series expansion, then series reversion and transformation of the result into a $[n,n+1]$ Padé approximant.

This would give
$$x_{(3)}=\frac{60 (n-1) n^3 -24 n^2 \left(n^2-4\right)y+3 n \left(n^3-3 n^2-9 n-13\right)y^2} {60 (n-1) n^2 y+6 n \left(n^2+11\right)y^2+(n-1) \left(n^2+11\right)y^3  }$$

For the worked example, this gives $x_{(3)}=581.590$.

Comment: Thank you! I changed my estimate using Garys suggestion in order to improve it, but I have to admit that the solution in your edit works very well for a large range of values of $y$.

Comment: @AxelT. Glad to know ! In fact we could extend the Padé approximant to any higher order. Cheers :-)

Comment: I've seen that you've put the Padé approximant to good use previously with good success, so I guess I'd better learn it. I reccon that I would be able to use the same method for small values of $x$ as well.